# select multiple observations by value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with multiple observations for each ID like this:

**edit**: updated data frame

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4), V1=c("A","B","C","A","A","B","B","C","A"),
             V2=rnorm(9))

> df
  ID V1          V2
1  1  A  1.57707547
2  1  B -0.76022296
3  1  C -0.82693346
4  2  A  1.80888747
5  2  A -0.53173950
6  3  B -1.18705727
7  3  B  0.04325324
8  3  C -0.33361802
9  4  A -0.02358198
```

Now I want to select all rows per ID in the following way:

- If ID has observations for "A", select these rows
- If ID has observations for "B", select these rows
- If ID has observations for both "A" and "B", select only rows with "A"

In my example I want to have this:

```
    ID V1          V2
  1  1  A  1.57707547
  2  2  A  1.80888747
  3  2  A -0.53173950
  4  3  B -1.18705727
  5  3  B  0.04325324
  6  4  A -0.02358198
```

I'd also like to see a `dplyr` solution if applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option with `dplyr`.  We group by 'ID' column, `filter` the rows that have either 'A' or 'B' rows, do another `filter` to check the number of unique elements in 'V1' (`n_distinct(V1)`).  If it is greater than 1, and the element is 'A' we select it (`n_distinct(V1)>1 & V1=='A'`) or we select all the length of unique elements as 1.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    filter(V1 %in% c('A', 'B'))%>%
    filter(n_distinct(V1)>1 & V1=='A'|n_distinct(V1)==1)
 #  ID V1          V2
 #1  1  A  1.57707547
 #2  2  A  1.80888747
 #3  2  A -0.53173950
 #4  3  B -1.18705727
 #5  3  B  0.04325324
 #6  4  A -0.02358198
```

Maybe we can use a modified version using single `filter`. We check if the number of unique elements in 'V1' is greater than 1 and if none of the elements are 'A' (`all(V1!='A')`) and if the element is 'B', we select that row, or if the number of distinct elements are greater than 1 and there is a 'A' element in it, select that row or if the number of unique element is 1 and the element is either 'A' or 'B', select the row.

```
 df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(V1)>1 & all(V1 !='A') & V1=='B'|n_distinct(V1)>1 & 
            V1=='A' |n_distinct(V1)==1 & V1 %in% c('A', 'B') )
 #   ID V1          V2
 #1  1  A  1.57707547
 #2  2  A  1.80888747
 #3  2  A -0.53173950
 #4  3  B -1.18705727
 #5  3  B  0.04325324
 #6  4  A -0.02358198
```

Or a bit more compact one would be (Inspired from @MichaelChirico's post).  We group by 'ID', and `filter` either V1 with 'A' rows or 'B' and without any 'A' rows.

```
 df %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     filter(V1=='A'|V1=='B'&!any(V1=='A'))
 #  ID V1          V2
 #1  1  A  1.57707547
 #2  2  A  1.80888747
 #3  2  A -0.53173950
 #4  3  B -1.18705727
 #5  3  B  0.04325324
 #6  4  A -0.02358198
```

Comment: thanks, very nice. Is there a way to combine this with other filtering? For example I already use these filters on the same data set: `df %>% filter(V1=="G" | V1=="Z")`

Comment: @spore234 I modified with a new version.  Can you check it that works

Comment: the second solution produces a different result, no "B"s are selected in my real data set. This may be because there are very often more than one "B" observation for any ID, unlike in my example data.

Comment: @spore234 I didn't test it properly.  If you can update with an example that gives a different result, I can try it again.

Comment: I modified the data set, your first solution works, the second not.

Comment: @spore234 I modified it with a single filter but I think a double filter looks more easier to understand

Answer (score 2):

In `data.table`, this can be readily done with:

```
library(data.table); setDT(df)
df[df[,.I[V1=="A"|(V1=="B"&!"A"%in%unique(V1))],by=ID]$V1]
```

The inner `df` call picks the indices (`.I`) where either a) `V1` is `A` or b) `V1` is `B` and there are no other `A` element among the `V1` for that `ID` (that is, this is done `by` `ID`); `$V1` extracts these indices and passes them back to the outer `df`.

(It may be confusing that we extract `V1` because there's a column in the original table called `V1`, but the `V1` we extract is different; to see this, consider this alternative where we name the outcome variable:

```
df[df[,.(ind=.I[V1=="A"|(V1=="B"&!"A"%in%unique(V1))]),by=ID]$ind]
```

Here, we name the index variable `ind`, so we have to extract `ind` instead of `V1`)